# Whats the difference between using 'this' and the object name for reference inside the object?

Tags: javascript

If I have the following code:

```
var obj = {

    x: 34,

    init: function() {
        alert(this.x);
        alert(obj.x)
    }

};
```

Both alerts displays 34. But what is the difference, and is one better than the other?

http://jsfiddle.net/4scz435q/

I made a test in jsperf, and it seems `this` is a bit faster, but I still don't understand the inner workings of the two versions.
http://jsperf.com/name-vs-this-in-obj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides the shadowing and so on mentioned in the previous answers, using `this` is more generic and thus will work more effectively in certain scenarios. Let me illustrate.

```
var object = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    print: function () {
        console.log(object.name);
    }
};

var anotherObject = Object.create(object);

object.print(); // John Doe
anotherObject.print(); // John Doe

anotherObject.name = 'Jane Doe';
console.log(anotherObject.name); // Jane Doe
anotherObject.print(); // John Doe
```

What I'm doing here is that I'm creating an `object` that has a name 'John Doe' and then I  create `anotherObject` that inherits from it. Now in this scenario, you would expect `anotherObject.print()` to print its own name. But it doesn't.

This is because your function is tied to that particular object. If I would have used `this` instead, it would have referred to the new object appropriately.

Also, imagine what happens if I were to do this.

```
delete object.name;
anotherObject.print() // Error!
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uxy08zxz/

This is because even though you think it has nothing to do with that previous object, its function still refers to that very property. Doesn't it?

**Hence, keep it generic. Use `this`. Keeps your code drier, I say.**

Comment: Thanks, @Tom. But yes, I feel like this is a much more important point when dealing with `this` than shadowing. This is potentially breaking in a **lot** of instances!

Answer (score 3):

`this` inside the function is not necessarily the same as `obj`. It depends on how the function is called.

- if called using `obj.init()`, `obj` will be the same as `this`.
- if called using an event handler, or something like setTimeout `setTimeout(obj.init, 500)`, `this` will be the global object (`window` in browsers, unless you're using strict mode)

[Good MDN reference on all of this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: I wouldn't use setTimeout(obj.init, 500), to get more consistent behavior I would use setTimeout(function(){obj.init()}, 500)

Comment: Well yes, but that was my point to show that `this` isn't always the same object.

Comment: Well yes, but what I am trying to say is, if you write your code well, you can be sure what     this refers to. As a matter of fact, for the creater of this question, I would really stay away from using obj.x inside of the obj. You can run into many problems, to to mention the debug and minification hell. Use "this" to refer to the parent object. In case you need to use callbacks or other anonymous functions, save instance into variable: var inst = this;

Comment: Heck, `this` would be undefined when run inside an anonymous function inside your `setTimeout()` in strict mode.

Comment: The best practice would be to to explicitly set `self` as `this` if you feel like you will need access to the calling object inside an anonymous function. And in generic cases like in your question, just use `this`. Also, all this will get simpler with ES6 with its arrow functions and lexical scoping.

Comment: I now played around with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4scz435q/2/ - how come you have to set `this` just before the setTimeout `inst2`, and you can't use the one on object instantiaton `inst`?

Answer (score 2):

I would say there are two differences here:

1. `this` can get shadowed. Creating an anonymous function in JavaScript can unfortunately replace `this` with a reference to the new anonymous function you're in, and not the current object you want access to.
2. When you're not worrying about shadowing, `this` is more flexible if the name of the object changes.

`this` is probably faster in this case because JavaScript won't need to look up the reference.