# Scope of an object literal within a function inside the object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am running three snippets of code. The first one works, while the second and third does not work. I am not sure I understand why the second and third does not work.

```
user2 = { 
          handle :"mytext", 
          alertName: function(){
                     alert(this.handle);}
        };
user2.handle;  //"mytext"
user2.alertName() // alerts "mytext"
```

Here, I understand that handle is assigned to the user2 object and is a key on the user2 object. Hence, when I call user2.alertName(), this.handle refers to user2.handle, so prints out the correct value.

However, why doesn't the following two versions of code work:

```
user2 = { 
          handle :"mytext", 
          alertName: function(){
                     alert(handle);}
        };

user2.handle;  //"mytext"
user2.alertName()  // gives error that handle is not defined in the console
```

and

```
user2 = { 
          handle :"mytext", 
          alertName: function(handle){
                     alert(handle);}
        };

user2.handle;  //"mytext"
user2.alertName()  //gives undefined in the alert popup
```

As far as I understand scope, handle which is defined at user2 object should be available to function which is a sub-scope of user2.
Am I missing something basic here.Apologies if this seems like a noob question, but I think I got it and always keep coming back here. And I can't get a clear answer anywhere as to why the second or the third doesn't make sense when I look for documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and directing me to an important point here. Using  object name and 'this' are not the same. I looked up the following answer to understand the difference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226693/whats-the-difference-between-using-this-and-the-object-name-for-reference-insi. Hope it helps some others too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user2 = { 
          handle :"mytext", 
          alertName: function(){
                     alert(handle);}
        };

user2.handle;  //"mytext"
user2.alertName()  // gives error that handle is not defined in the console
```

`handle` is a `property` of the `object`, so you need to access the property of the object via `this` which refers to the `object`.

`alert(handle);` throws error coz its trying to find a variable named handle which is not in scope.

If you define the varibale handle `globally`, then you can access it in your `user2` `object`.

```
var handle="google";

user2 = { 
          handle :"mytext", 
          alertName: function(){
                     alert(handle);}
        };

alert(user2.handle);  //"mytext"
user2.alertName()  // gives error that handle is not defined in the console
```

Answer (score 2):

In your second and third code:

```
user2 = { 
          handle :"mytext", // handle is a property 
          alertName: function(){
                     alert(handle);}
        };
```

1. "handle" is a property of the object user2.
2. **this** is the object who's method you are invoking.
3. "handle" is a property of **this** inside the method "alertName".

Since, handle is not a variable defined, hence the error.
In the third case you're defining handle as an argument in the method signature but not passing any in the call, so it comes out as undefined.

Answer (score 1):

In second example, function 'alertName' expects a parameter 'handle'.
Call user2.alertName() without parameter results in undefined.

For works should be this:

```
user2.alertName(user2.handle);
```

Comment: That's interesting.So 'user2.handle' is still available inside. Is it that handle becomes ambiguous when the objects -  user2 or this - is not clearly mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

I will start with the code example followed by an explanation.

```
var user2 = { 
  handle :"mytext", 
  alertName: function() {
    //var handle is not defined in the current lexical scope or globally.
    alert(handle);
  }
};

user2.handle;  //"mytext"
user2.alertName()  // gives error that handle is not defined in the console
```

Explanation:
you are defining `user2.alertName`. Within this function you are calling `alert(handle)`. From what I can see `handle` is not defined within the current lexical scope, or globally, hence `undefined` is alerted.

```
var user2 = { 
  handle :"mytext", 
  alertName: function(handle){
    alert(handle);
  }
};

user2.handle;  //"mytext"
user2.alertName()  //gives undefined in the alert popup
```

Explanation:
You are defining `user2.alertName`. This function takes a parameter which is alerted.
When you invoke `user2.alertName()` you are not passing any variable or literal.
hence, `undefined` is alerted. 
to alert the `user2.handle` use:

```
user2.alertName(user2.handle);
```

I hope this helps,

Rhys

Answer (score 0):

```
user2 = { 
          handle :"mytext", 
          alertName: function(){
                     alert(this.handle);}
        };

user2.handle;  //"mytext"
user2.alertName()  // alerts "mytext"
```

handle is a property of the object, so you need to access the property of the object via this which refers to the object.