# Should you use "this" or refer directly to the parent object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

There are some cases in my program where you could either use "this" or just directly refer to the parent object (let's call this Parent) to carry out the same function.

```
let Parent = {};

Parent.func = function (foo) {
  this.bar = foo; // option 1
  Parent.bar = foo; // option 2
}
```

Is there any reason, perhaps efficiency or just code convention, to use one of the options over the other?

For example, does the "this" keyword take more/less time to reference than Parent, or is this negligible? Or do people generally see using "this" in an example like the one given as bad practice or harder to read (or the opposite)?

Comment: This question is likely to invite a huge amount of opinion, varying from "`this` was a mistake in the JS language" to "fill your boots, OO is great". There's simply no right answer here.

Comment: here you can get the answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226693/whats-the-difference-between-using-this-and-the-object-name-for-reference-insi/25226751#25226751

Comment: You can use whatever you feel comfortable.

Comment: My opinion is that the amount of confusion caused by `this` (and the fact that it's entirely-context sensitive in its meaning) indicates to me that it increases the complexity of code and hence, decreases readability. But that's just an opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason to use `this` instead is that it's more composable - it can be called on objects *other* than `Parent` if required, and said flexibility can be useful to have as an option. For example:

```js
let Parent = {};

Parent.func = function (foo) {
  this.bar = foo;
}

const parentLikeObject = {};
Parent.func.call(parentLikeObject, 'parentLikeFoo');
console.log(parentLikeObject);
```

If you referenced `Parent` instead of `this` inside `.func`, this sort of thing would be impossible.

Referencing the object the function is called on (the `this`) is a very common pattern that allows for more reusable code. For example, this is how `forEach` can be used on NodeLists on older browsers which don't support `NodeList.prototype.forEach`:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('div'),
  div => console.log(div.textContent)
);
```

```html
<div>foo</div>
<div>bar</div>
```

It's not exactly the same, because that's a method on the prototype, but the general idea is similar.